# How do you specify the URL for "More help on this function" in Excel?

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm currently developing an Excel Add-in and am facing some trouble getting through store validation.

Specifically, when clicking the button in the image below, it results in "No help available."

[Excel - Mysterious More Help Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsYZO.png)

I have added a "helpurl" to the metadata in my functions.json file, but this button still does not work. Does anyone know where I have to make this change in order to get this URL linking somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for raising your question. You'd better to provide more details to help us repro. You can reproduce this behavior using the Script Lab tool and export it as a gist. Then add the gist URL to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.